# VSTS Rest API for C# - How to return the full comments when getting a list of commits?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

The below API method returns commit details for all `commitIds`, but the comments are truncated, is there a way to get the full comments for each commit without having to make a separate API call for each commit?

`GetCommitsAsync(repositoryId, new GitQueryCommitsCriteria() { Ids = commitIds });`

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test, we cannot get the full comments with the `GetCommitsAsync` method, no parameters to expand the comment length, especially for the Multi-line comments (Line break ).

And when retrieve the commits using REST API ([Get Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/rest/api/vsts/git/commits/get%20commits?view=vsts-rest-4.1)) you can see that `"commentTruncated": true,`

So, even with the REST API we cannot get the full comments. There's already a [user voice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/16950181-using-tfs-git-rest-api-to-get-commits-the-comment) submitted to suggest the feature, but it's not planed yet.

However we can use the [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) command to get the full comments for all the commits:

```
git log --first-parent > export.csv
```

You can also format it to display a commit per line:

```
git log --first-parent --format="%h;%ci;%cn;%s;%N" > export.csv
```

You can also reference this thread : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/587cedd4-ed32-421a-9aaf-4040c77ce1f5/tfs-git-api-commits-maxcommentlength-limited-to-100-chars-in-the-comments-today?forum=tfsgeneral

Comment: I am using the C# Rest API, so I cannot use the git log command. I have switched to a different API method now, but I'm sure it will be useful if a parameter was added to the GetCommitsAsync to allow full comments.